# NGINX proxy_server redirect HTTP code 301

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to implement a simple authentication with NGINX and PHP (I'm a complete NGINX noob).

Here's the relevant part of my NGINX conf file:

```
location /main {
auth_request /auth;
...
}

location = /auth {
internal;
proxy_pass https://www.mydomain/auth/auth.php;
proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
proxy_set_header  X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

I'm still testing, so my PHP file just returns HTTP code 202:

```
<?php
http_response_code(202);
?>
```

The problem is that NGINX calls the PHP page, as expected, but returns 301 (moved) instead of 202.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: `202` is being returned to nginx saying auth is ok. Nginx is not supposed to pass this further as such. `The ngx_http_auth_request_module module (1.5.4+) implements client authorization based on the result of a subrequest. If the subrequest returns a 2xx response code, the access is allowed. If it returns 401 or 403, the access is denied with the corresponding error code. Any other response code returned by the subrequest is considered an error.`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I understand that if the subrequest returns any other code than 2xx then the access is denied. The PHP file is returning 202 but somehow the NGINX is telling auth_request that the subrequest answered 301... my question is why and what should I do to correct it.

Comment: Do a `curl -v -H 'X-Original-URI:/main' https://www.mydomain/auth/auth.php` and see what you get? also do a `curl -v https://site/main` and see what response is being returned. Post these in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the NGINX conf and solved it:

```
location /main {
auth_request /auth;
...
}

location = /auth {
internal;
**proxy_set_header Host mydomain;**
proxy_pass https://www.mydomain/auth/auth.php;
proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
proxy_set_header  X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```